# Prolog Zip Function

Tags: prolog

Im in rew to Prolog. I'm trying to write a `zip` function. The question goes like this.

`zip(L1, L2, X)`: The list `X` is formed by “zipping” the first 2 arguments.

the result should be like this:

```
?- zip([a, b, c], [x, y, z], X).
L = [a, x, b, y, c, z]
?- zip([a, b], [x, y, z], X).
false
?- zip([a, b, c, d], X, [a, p, b, q, c, r, d, s]).
X = [p, q, r, s]
```

I have done this so far.
I can get the result for 1st 3rd but not the 2nd one. Can anybody can help me solving it for the 2nd one? thank you

```
zip([X],[Y],[X,Y]).  
zip([], [], []).
zip([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [X,Y|Zs]) :-
   zip(Xs,Ys,Zs).

zip([X|Xs],[],[X|Xs]).
zip([Y|Ys],[],[Y|Ys]).

zip(Xs, [], Xs).
zip([], Ys, Ys).
```

How do I define this function where:
`allsame(L)`: The list `L` contains identical elements.
I should get this.

```
?- allsame([b, b, b]).
true
?- allsame([c, c, c, Y, c, c, X, c]).
X = c, Y = c
```

Comment: It is quite unusual that your predicate should fail if the first two arguments are given. Also, the name is rather `interlace` or similar. `zip` is often considered to be a `map`-like function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had it:

```
zip([], [], []).
zip([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [X,Y|Zs]) :- zip(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

This alone is enough to define the relation you're seeking. The extra clauses don't help.

Test:

```
?- zip([a, b, c], [x, y, z], X).
X = [a, x, b, y, c, z].

?- zip([a, b], [x, y, z], X).
false.

?- zip([a, b, c, d], X, [a, p, b, q, c, r, d, s]).
X = [p, q, r, s].
```

Comment: Thank you m09. i m still new at this. i have one more thing. What can i do to get this. 

allsame(L): The list L contains identical elements. e.g.,

    ?- allsame([b, b, b]).
    true
    ?- allsame([c, c, c, Y, c, c, X, c]).
    X = c, Y = c

Answer (score 4):

@m09 gave the correct answer. But I'd like to explain why what you have isn't correct:

```
(1) zip([X],[Y],[X,Y]).
```

This rule says that `[X,Y]` is what you get when you zip `[X]` with `[Y]`. That is correct, and will not lead to a problem. The rule is simply redundant with the rules below (which I'll explain...).

```
(2) zip([], [], []).
```

This rule says `[]` is what you get when you zip `[]` with `[]` which is correct and as simple a rule as you can have for zip.

```
(3) zip([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [X,Y|Zs]) :-
        zip(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

This rule says that `[X,Y|Zs]` is what you get when you zip `[X|Xs]` with `[Y|Ys]` *if* `Zs` is what you get when you zip `Xs` with `Ys`. That is also logical and correct. Notice that `zip([X], [Y], [X,Y])` is `zip([X|[]], [Y|[]], [X,Y|[]]).` so it can be derived from rules (2) and (3). It would match rule (3) first, `zip([X|[]], [Y|[]], [X,Y|Zs]) :- zip([], [], Zs).`, then `Zs` would become `[]` by rule (2)`.

```
(4) zip([X|Xs],[],[X|Xs]).
(5) zip([Y|Ys],[],[Y|Ys]).
```

Rule (4) says `[X|Xs]` is what you get when you zip `[X|Xs]` with `[]`. Rule (5) says exactly the same thing, logically, only with a different variable name. These are incorrect, since that would mean, for example, `zip([a,b,c], [], Z)` would be true if `Z = [a,b,c]`.

```
(6) zip(Xs, [], Xs).
```

This rule says that `Xs` is what you get when you zip `Xs` with `[]`. Or stated another way, *any* input, zipped with `[]`, would be that input value again. It wouldn't even have to be a list! This is clearly incorrect. Queries like `zip(x, [], Z)` would succeed with `Z = x`, and `zip(friend(bill,mary), [], Z)` would succeed with `Z = friend(bill,mary)`.

```
(7) zip([], Ys, Ys).
```

This rule says that `Ys` is what you get when you zip `[]` with `Ys`. It is incorrect for the same reason (6) is incorrect. In fact, this rule, combined with (2) and (3) are why the query `zip([a, b], [x, y, z], X).` will yield a result rather than fail. Rules (2) and (3) will recurse to `zip([b], [y,z], [b,y|T]) :- zip([], [z], T).` and then `zip([], [z], T)` will finally succeed on rule (7) with `T = [z]`, and ultimately yielding a final result to `zip([a, b], [x, y, z], X)` of `X = [a, x, b, y, z]`.

Comment: A very fine answer . I suggest better than "This rule says that [X,Y|Zs] is what you get when you zip [X|Xs] with [Y|Ys] **if** Zs is what you get when you zip Xs with Ys. That is also logical and correct." is "This rule says that [X,Y|Zs] is what you get when you zip [X|Xs] with [Y|Ys] **implies that** Zs is what you get when you zip Xs with Ys. That is also logical and correct." . A minor but very _logical_ distinction .

Comment: @Kintalken thank you for the kind comment. Actually, in Prolog, `head :- body` is an implication in reverse: `body -> head`. The `head` is true (or is provable) *if* the `body` is true (provable) but not necessarily the other way around since other conditions may prove the `head` true as well (in the instance, for example, when there are multiple predicate clauses for the `head`). In other words, the `head` can be deduced from the `body` but not necessarily the other way around.

Comment: In Your comment You demonstrate a (common) misunderstanding of '->' . The important distinction between ':-' and `->' is that ':-' is __semantik__ but `->` is __syntaktik__ . Thus `a -> b` means "for a to be true first b must also be true" but because __syntaktik__ b must have a prior existence fully determined by the existing formal definitions . Thus `a :- b` means "for a to be true then b must also be true" (same) but! b now might not have a formal __syntaktik__ existence it might instead be an ephemeral __semantik__ determination , perhaps a calculation .

Comment: "implies" does not mean "determines" , quite the opposite : if a implies b it means that because there is an a by inductive reasoning the b must already have happened . Thus if "wet -> raining" it means that "there is wet it must have been raining" . But "wet => raining" means "there is raining so now also there is wet" . The Prolog ":-" is equivalent to "=>" . Nothing but confusion and certainly no canonical understanding can be gained by Google search on this topic "implication" it is a major area of confusion and wrong information .

Comment: In Your comment You write "the head can be deduced from the body but not necessarily the other way around." but! "deduce" is not a mere drop-in replacement for "to reason" (common mistake) : it has a specific meaning and in particular it must mean the opposite of "induce" . `status(wet) => location(outside) & weather(raining)` is an __deduktion__ stating "if the location is outside and it is raining then the status is wet" whereas `status(wet) & location(outside) -> weather(raining)` is an __induktion__ stating "if the status is wet and the location is outside then it must be raining" .

Comment: @Kintalken I don't believe I am misunderstanding, although I probably misued the term "deduce". You said that `a :- b` means that "for a to be true then b must also be true".  In prolog in particular, this is sufficient in order to also say that "if b is true, then a is true" or that "b implies a" if I oversimplify the terminology. In other words, "a is provable if b is provable" which is my original tenet. The meaning of `a :- b` is not that "a implies b" which is what you were basically saying in your first comment (unless I misunderstood it).

Comment: "implies" cannot mean that something is caused to happen it must be conditional upon what has already happenned .

Consider the statement "the evidence implicates him in the bombing" ; also servicable as "the evidence __implies __ his involvement in the bombing" .

It would be a miscarriage of justice and a corruption if the evidence was created after the bombing to make the statement true .

Comment: ```b -> a``` and ```b => a``` OUI have the same thing to say about __truth__ : both have the __truth__ meaning of "if '`a`' is true then as consequence that '`a`' is true '`b`' is also true" .

```b -> a``` and ```b => a``` NON have the same thing to say about __cause__ . ```b => a``` means that necessarily it is the truth of '`b`' that is an __cause__ over which '`a`' becomes true ; ```b -> a``` imposes no semantik of __cause__ instead it means that '`b`' as true is an condition under which '`a`' is true .

Comment: This is an very important distinction because causality and the time-order it necessitates is perhaps the most frequently occurring hidden variable in human reasoning .